# Open source ESBs supporting web service transactions?

Tags: web-services, mule, esb, soa, apache-servicemix

Do any of the major open source ESBs such as Mule or ServiceMix properly support web service transaction specifications (like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Atomic_Transaction)?

I've just briefly looked but it seems like support is not very good.

I would like to use the ESB to build macro services by composing from modular smaller services. I think this would be a pretty typical use of an ESB, and I don't see how you can implement anything practical if you don't have transactions.

Answer (score 1):

WS Atomic Transaction is not in the [list of supported WS-standards for Mule](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Supported+Web+Service+Standards), so no luck here.

In term of design, the "transaction over SOAP" paradigm never really took off. Approaches likes *stateful conversations with idempotent retries and compensations* is usually what people prefer when integrating services over HTTP. It sure is more work than simply flipping the "transaction" switch on.